# How to obtain 6 Portfolios Formed on Size and Operating Profitability weekly data

Tags: fama-french

How to Compound 6 Portfolios Formed on Size and Operating Profitability daily data, and then computer 6 Portfolios Formed on Size and Operating Profitability weekly data？

Comment: Ken French doesn't provide returns on such a high frequency. Thus, you have to calculate them yourself. Form $2\times 3$ portfolios and calculate value-weighted portfolios using daily data. Then compound those returns to weekly returns.